# Script started with drush php-script would not exit after ctrl+c

Tags: drupal, drush

I'm running a big php script with drush. The script takes really long time to run - probably few hours, and I would like to stop it whenever I want. 
Here is an example php script I'm running:

```
$iter = 1;
while( $iter <= 50 ){
    echo "iteration no ". $iter ."\n";
    $iter++;
    sleep( 1 );
}
```

Here is the command I'm running it with:

```
$ drush php-script userstest.php
```

When I press CTRL+C, the drush command stops, but the php script continues to run.
Here is how it looks:

```
$ drush php-script userstest.php
iteration no 1
iteration no 2
iteration no 3


$ iteration no 4
iteration no 5
iteration no 6
iteration no 7
^C

$ iteration no 8
iteration no 9
iteration no 10
iteration no 11
^C

$ iteration no 12
iteration no 13
iteration no 14
iteration no 15
```

And it goes on until the php script it actually done.
How can I stop the script as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has Drush have no parameter of function for that, try `drush help`? If not...

Verify if the process that is run is a PHP process then:

```
killall -u yourusername php
```

or whatever process is run by drush.

I think that's the only method you can achieve this in this case.

Comment: That actually worked! Thanks a lot!
The only thing is I'm on Windows 7 and running Drush under Cygwin. No php processes are listed in process list (using ps aux under Cygwin) and killall doesn't work there. So I had to use taskkill /F /IM php.exe in cmd